# Clarification on U-Tube force analysis

Tags: fluid-dynamics

This is just a clarifying question about Chester Miller (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/102308/chester-miller)'s answer to the following question: [Oscillations in U-tube](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266757/oscillations-in-u-tube). Sorry if this is not the place to ask, but I don't have enough reputation to comment on his original answer so I figured I'd give this a shot. Chester, if this gets marked as a duplicate, I would really appreciate it if you are able to reach out to me at lcoumb@gmail.com :)

I'm trying to determine the equation for oscillation of a U-tube specifically using force analysis (I already understand how to do so using conservation of energy). Chester created the following equations for the oscillation of fluid in a U-tube. My question is regarding the integration that happened between equations (5) and (6): I understand (more or less) the integration that occurred on the right side, but am unclear on what happened on the left side. Would it be possible to explain this in further detail?
Thanks so much!!

If we divide Eqn. 1 by $S\Delta z$ and take the limit as $\Delta z$ approaches zero, we obtain:$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}+\rho g=-\rho\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\tag{3}$$
Eqn. 3 applies to the region above point A in the left column.  Similarly, for the horizontal region between points A and B, we have: $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=-\rho\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\tag{4}$$where y is the horizontal coordinate measured from A to C.  Finally, for the right hand column above point B, we have:  $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}+\rho g=+\rho\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\tag{5}$$
If we integratd these equations along the continuous path (contour) between the top of the left column at z = h+x (where the pressure is atmospheric) to the top of the right column at z = h-x (where the pressure is again atmospheric), where h is the equilibrium height, we obtain:$$2\rho g x=-L\rho \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\tag{6}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{h+x}^{h-x}{\rho gdz}=\int_{h+x}^{0}{\rho gdz}+\int_{0}^{h-x}{\rho gdz}=-2\rho g x$$